# How .NET Core 2.1 Models with foreign keys should be done right way?

Tags: c#, .net

I have two tables:

```
Table A 
Id PK
Name

Table B
Id PK
TableARowId FK
```

- How this should be achieved via migrations?
- How models in codebase and context should reflect this relationship
  if in the future I will need return custom response from **Table B**?

Response example:

```
 {
        Id: 123,
        NameOfTableARowById: Table A Row
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<A>(entity =>
          {
            entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            entity.ToTable("A");
            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                });
      modelBuilder.Entity<B>(entity =>
                {

           entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
           entity.ToTable("B");
           entity.HasOne(d => d.A)
                        .WithMany(p => p.B)
                        .HasForeignKey(d => d.TableARowId)
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                        .HasConstraintName("FK_B_ToA");
                });
```